# Wi-fi adapter AR9285 does not work on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I recently got an old Sony Vaio notebook and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it.
The only issue I encountered was when I tried to connect to the wifi, cable works fine though.

The adapter works normally; when I switch if off with the hardware switch, it detects, everything seems fine. But it doesn't detect any networks. When I try, it reads "No networks".

I didn't find any valid solutions online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after some research someone suggested it could be that the wi-fi antenna wasn't physically connected. And that was the case.